# Take me to next pay period end date?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a formula that will take me to the next pay period end date.

For example, if the employee's leave of absence is going to go unpaid effective 1-1-15, I want a formula that will tell me when the last day of the pay period is for 1-1-15. We have biweekly pay periods.

Comment: Look at the workday function.  It should assist.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** define your pay periods.

In your case, it seems pay periods are simply every other week, always on the same day of the week. You may get away with simply writing a formula that checks to see if the target date rounds into a number divisible by 14; however in the case of a holiday (which may push the payment into the prior day or the following Monday depending on holdiay), I recommend creating a list manually.

To do this, go to a new sheet (let's say Sheet2). On A1, write the date of the last pay period which just happened. Then on A2 and drag down, use the formula:

```
=A1+14
```

However, after dragging this down to the end of the year, I recommend that you go back and manually confirm that each date is appropriate (ie: are there any special cases?

**Step 2**
Use a lookup formula to check which pay period a date falls into. Here I'll assume a simple case, where Sheet1 A1 contains the date that an employee begins unpaid leave, and Sheet1 B1 will contain the pay period which that date falls into:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!A:A,1,1)
```

This will look for the value in A1 on Sheet2 - if it falls on the exact day, it will spit it back to you. If it doesn't fall on the exact day, it will give you the next closest date after that [make sure this rounds the way you want; I couldn't quite get a sense of the actual response you wanted].